# I am inserting multiple checkboxes values in laravel. How can I do this?

Tags: laravel, checkbox, controller

I want to insert multiple checkbox values and more than one email I am doing it with foreach loop. Everything is working fine but when 1 email is empty. It's inserting null in the email field and also null checkbox is also inserting full data.

it is my form with 20 inputs

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{route('send.document')}}">
    @csrf 
   // 1st Email
    <input type="email"  name="email[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="sign">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="initial">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="date">
    <input type="checkbox"name="task[]"  value="cc">
    // 2nd Email
    <input type="email" name="email[]" >
    <input type="checkbox"name="task[]" value="sign">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="initial">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]"value="date">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="cc">
    // 3rd Email
    <input type="email" name="email[]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="sign">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="initial">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="date">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="cc">
    // 4th Email
    <input type="email" name="email[]" >
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="sign">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="initial">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="date">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="cc">
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```

and it is my route

```
 Route::post('/send-document',[SendDocumentController::class, 'sendDocToUser'])- 
    >name('send.document');
```

my controller

```
public function sendDocToUser(Request $request)
        {
            $UpdateFile = FileStorage::where('id', $request->id)->first();
            if (!empty($request->email)) {
                foreach($request->email as $mail) {
                    $save = new SendFile([
                        'Email' => $mail,
                        'senderId' => Auth::id(),
                        'fileName'=> $UpdateFile->uniqueFileName,
                        'task' => $request->task,
                    ]);
                    $save->save();
                }
            }
    }
```

database inserted data:

[image: database look like this]

and the form look like:
[image: it is my form picture]

Comment: you should add an hidden array and run the foreach on that bcoz when the email is empty it's not considered in loop

Comment: where I have to add ?

Comment: do you want to insert null record or not? like if 1 email is empty then you want to insert only 3 records in DB right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would restructure your `<form>` slightly to incorporate a `key` on the `task[]` `checkbox`es and to also leverage looping.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('fake.store') }}">
    @csrf()

    @for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
        <input type="email" name="email[]" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="task[{{$i}}][]" value="sign" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="task[{{$i}}][]" value="initial" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="task[{{$i}}][]" value="cc" />
        <input type="checkbox" name="task[{{$i}}][]" value="date" />
    @endfor
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

You could if you wanted pass the upper limit for `$i` into the view as a parameter from your `Controller` function (see sandbox at the end for this).

This will submit your `task` `checkbox`es as an `array` but with an index of `$i` which we will use as a hook to remove based on whether the `email[]` field with the corresponding index is `null`.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $notNullEmails = array_filter($request->email);

    $merged = [];
    foreach ($notNullEmails as $key => $value) {
        $merged[] = ['email' => $notNullEmails[$key], 'task' => $request->task[$key]];
    }

    dump($merged);
}
```

The result of the above being:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => "email@domain.com"
    "task" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "initial"
      1 => "cc"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "email" => "email@domain.com"
    "task" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "sign"
      1 => "date"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Here is a functional example on [PHPSandbox.io](https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/cuwa1?layout=EditorPreview&defaultPath=%2F&theme=dark&showExplorer=no&openedFiles=).